# Google Data Studio Multiple Date Range

Tags: google-data-studio

I'm a Data Studio newby so pardon me if my question seems stupid, I've a very simple dataset to report (see a record sample below):

```
CheckIn         CheckOut       Rate 

2017-01-01      2017-01-10     $100
```

I would like to see in my report/chart $100 from the 1st of January to 9th of January, obviously the total will be $900.

I can't figure out how to do, how to solve this?